# Is there a way to change local variables partway through switch case without exiting the switch statement?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm dealing with a rather large enumeration, which can conceptually be divided as representing four different categories. Currently I'm using this enumeration in a switch case statement in order to map values into four separate arrays (in line with the four different categories).

What I'm curious about is if it is possible to change a locally defined variable after arbitrary cases in the switch case statement. This would allow for the ability to break the switch statement into these four different sections, and value assignments that would occur for each case -- if equivalent -- can occur at these sections.

A simplified example what I'm going for is as follows:

**Setup**

```
enum incidental_indexes {
arr1_0, arr1_2, arr2_0, arr1_1, arr2_1
} indexes;

struct foobar{ 
int arr1[3];
int arr2[2];
}

enum indexes unknown_index = ???; // In my code there are two separate indexes being mapped 
                               // from one another, so for the sake of example imagine that 
                               // this index is unknown
enum indexes curr_index = arr1_1;   //Value here does not matter
struct foobar my_struc;
int * curr_arr;
int mapped_index;
```

**Brute force approach**

```
switch(unknown_index){
 case(arr1_0):
    curr_arr = my_struc.arr_1; //First category array
    curr_index = arr1_0;
    break;
 case(arr1_1):
    curr_arr = my_struc.arr_1; //First category array, again
    curr_index = arr1_1;
    break;
 case(arr1_2):
    curr_arr = my_struc.arr_1; //First category array, again, again
    curr_index = arr1_2;
    break;
 case(arr2_0):
    curr_index = arr2_0;
    curr_arr = my_struc.arr_2;  //Second category array
    break;
 case(arr2_1):
    curr_index = arr2_1;
    curr_arr = my_struc.arr_2;  //....
    break;
}
```

**Ideal Approach**

```
switch(unknown_index){
 default:   //Notice no break.
    curr_arr = my_struc.arr_1; //First category array
 case(arr1_0):
    curr_index = arr1_0;
    break;
 case(arr1_1):
    curr_index = arr1_1;
    break;
 case(arr1_2):
    curr_index = arr1_2;
    break;
 default: //Something like a second default, however disallowed 
    curr_arr = my_struc.arr_2;  //Second category array
 case(arr2_0):
    curr_index = arr2_0;
    break;
 case(arr2_1):
    curr_index = arr2_1;
    break;
}
```

The functional benefits are obviously nill, however I'm curious if this functionality even exists in C, or if there is perhaps a better method for executing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: `case` labels are no functions, so you should not use parenthesis. (The same for `return`, btw.)

Comment: Maybe using two `switch`es is the better approach. Not sure what you actually want to accomplish with the redefinition. `case` labels are similar to `goto`, not like a chain of `if` statements  Just let the compiler optimise this.

Comment: Your various definitions comprising `arr` and `_` and `number` don't suit humans at all. A programming language is supposed to be a bridge between the machine and the human mind. Your `switch` statement just seems to be a blur of permutations of those three things plus `curr`.

Comment: @Olaf  Woops-- parenthesis was a mistake. And I should have added that I do currently have two four implemented, and did mean if there was a way in which to get them all under one block.

Comment: @WeatherVane An example is supposed to be a bridge between the code and humans. My view is that there was no need to provide excessive arbitrary imagery to portray the purpose of a straightforward example. If that's what you needed, then please find your way to the closest library that houses a collection of Aesop's Fables.

Comment: Then why did you? Three lines or so would have sufficed to illustrate a simple question.

Comment: @WeatherVane As to not invite answers that would be irrelevant due to lack of detail. Of course I probably could have condensed it down by a few lines, but isn't that almost always the case? At any rate, I doubt your question was sincere, and I can guarantee that mine is rhetorical. Enjoy your night.

Comment: Thank you, that is why SO asks for MCVE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch statements only perform a single branch, so you can't jump around inside of the switch like that.  What you can do however is group certain cases together without a `break` in between:

```
switch(curr_index){
 case arr1_0:
 case arr1_1:
 case arr1_2:
    curr_arr = my_struc.arr_1;
    break;
 case arr2_0:
 case arr2_1:
    curr_arr = my_struc.arr_2;
    break;
}
```

EDIT:

For the index assignment part, you could do a second `switch` like this:

```
switch(unknown_index){
 case arr1_0:
    curr_index = arr1_0;
    break;
 case arr1_1:
    curr_index = arr1_1;
    break;
 case arr1_2:
    curr_index = arr1_2;
    break;
 case arr2_0:
    curr_index = arr2_0;
    break;
 case arr2_1:
    curr_index = arr2_1;
    break;
}
```

But since you're always assigning whatever the value of `unknown_index` is, the above is the same as this:

```
curr_index = unknown_index;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what you mean by jump around. Aware of the example you suggest, however each case does have a specific assignment associated with it (index), in addition to the array assignment with respect to its categorization. 

Of course I could also add some checks to see if its already been assigned, however at that point it doesn't feel far off from using flags. At that point I'm personally inclined to use several switches instead.

Comment: @TolkienWASP See my edit regarding the index assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up dbush, separating the task into several switch statements is what I had implemented initially, and it seems to be the best means of dealing with what I was going for.

Answer (score 1):

One, no.

Two, just use ifs and elses. As the saying goes, when you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail. `switch` is a really weird "hammer" to try applying to everything.

Three, um, I guess you could use `goto` everywhere, but we decided this was a bad idea and creates horribly messes of code in the 80s or something.

Answer (score 0):

Within a switch you have access to all the locally defined variables.  I'm not quite sure I understand your question... it seems like what you're trying to do is best accomplished by 2 switches:

```
switch(unknown_index){
 case(arr1_0):
 case(arr1_1):
 case(arr1_2):
    curr_arr = my_struc.arr_1; //First category array, again, again
    break;
 case(arr2_0):
 case(arr2_1):
    curr_arr = my_struc.arr_2;  //....
    break;
}
switch(unknown_index){
 case(arr1_0):
    curr_index = arr1_0;
    break;
 case(arr1_1):
    curr_index = arr1_1;
    break;
 case(arr1_2):
    curr_index = arr1_2;
    break;
 case(arr2_0):
    curr_index = arr2_0;
    break;
 case(arr2_1):
    curr_index = arr2_1;
    break;
}
```